# How can I put the QTY field in ASC order?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012. Since `GROUP_CONCAT` isn't a thing I've ended up using the XML method (shout out to Sean ;), no screenshots on this one bud :)).

When I try to do the `ORDER BY` clause I receive this error:

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
>   Total execution time: 00:00:00.068

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ID], [STATUS], [EXPECTED_WIN_DATE], [CUSTOMER_ID],[CUSTOMER_PART_ID] As [Style #],
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FLOOR(QTY))
        FROM QUOTE_PRICE
        JOIN QUOTE_LINE
        ON QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID
        WHERE QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE.ID
        ORDER BY 1 ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
) AS Quantity

FROM QUOTE

JOIN QUOTE_LINE
ON QUOTE.ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID

WHERE PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.STATUS = 'A'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE > '20170101'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL
Order By PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.ID ASC
-- Order By PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE ASC
```

Here is my sample data table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,STATUS VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL
    ,CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
    ,Style_ VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
    ,Quantity VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04631
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-10 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1008991Q'
    ,'50'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04640
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-03 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PRO300'
    ,'PRO3007848'
    ,'100'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04651
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009121Q'
    ,'1000,1250,1500,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04651
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009122Q'
    ,'1000,1250,1500,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04652
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009119Q'
    ,'1000,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04652
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009120Q'
    ,'1000,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04653
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009117Q'
    ,'1000,1500,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04653
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009118Q'
    ,'1000,1500,250,500,750'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04654
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009115Q'
    ,'1000,250,2500,4000,500,5000,750,8000'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04654
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009116Q'
    ,'1000,250,2500,4000,500,5000,750,8000'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04655
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'PEP100'
    ,'PEP1009114Q'
    ,'994'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04666
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-12 00:00:00.000'
    ,'CVS100'
    ,'CVS1009128S'
    ,'6500,7500,8000'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04667
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-16 00:00:00.000'
    ,'CVS100'
    ,'CVS1009129D'
    ,'6000'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04668
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-10 00:00:00.000'
    ,'EAR100'
    ,'EAR1009093S'
    ,'150,250,500'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04669
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-16 00:00:00.000'
    ,'DUR200'
    ,'DUR2008478'
    ,'1000,1500,600'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04670
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-10 00:00:00.000'
    ,'HAY100'
    ,'HAY1009098S1'
    ,'1000,500'
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (
    ID
    ,STATUS
    ,EXPECTED_WIN_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER_ID
    ,Style_
    ,Quantity
    )
VALUES (
    04670
    ,'A'
    ,'2018-10-10 00:00:00.000'
    ,'HAY100'
    ,'HAY1009098S2'
    ,'1000,500'
    );
```

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [ID], [STATUS], [EXPECTED_WIN_DATE], [CUSTOMER_ID],[CUSTOMER_PART_ID] As [Style #],
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FLOOR(QTY))
        FROM QUOTE_PRICE
        JOIN QUOTE_LINE
        ON QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID
        WHERE QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE.ID
        ORDER BY QUOTE_PRICE.QTY ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
) AS Quantity

FROM QUOTE

JOIN QUOTE_LINE
ON QUOTE.ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID

WHERE PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.STATUS = 'A'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE > '20170101'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL
Order By PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.ID ASC
-- Order By PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE ASC
```

Comment: NB: Your sample data has some duplicate values which violate its primary key constraint...

Comment: Your sample data is invalid. You have duplicate values for your primary key. ;) Not really sure how mytable relates to your query you posted. You have two tables in that query and neither of them are named MyTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple (but frowned up) way is to use the column number in your order by. In your query Quantity is column 6 so use `ORDER BY 6`. If you are just running this as an ad-hoc query, it's probably fine.

Another very simple way to do it is wrap your query in a select *  and put your order by on that query like this:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT DISTINCT [ID], [STATUS], [EXPECTED_WIN_DATE], [CUSTOMER_ID],

[CUSTOMER_PART_ID] As [Style #],
(
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FLOOR(QTY))
        FROM QUOTE_PRICE
        JOIN QUOTE_LINE
        ON QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID
        WHERE QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE.ID
        ORDER BY 1 ASC
        FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
) AS Quantity

FROM QUOTE

JOIN QUOTE_LINE
ON QUOTE.ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID

WHERE PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.STATUS = 'A'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.EXPECTED_WIN_DATE > '20170101'
AND PPV8.dbo.QUOTE.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL
) q
ORDER BY Quantity
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude!

Comment: But ordering by column ordinals is _such_ a bad idea. Have a look here from the (nearly 10 year old) [Bad Habits To Kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) series.

Comment: Excellent point, but if it's just for an ad-hoc query, why spend time doing it a different way when you could do this in about 2 seconds?

Comment: Because even for a one off query it is just oddball to use the ordinal position. You have stop and look to see what column number it is. Why not use the name?

Comment: I agree that using the name is better than the ordinal, but merely using the name doesn't work here because the name is an alias for a subquery. That's the whole point of the question. If I were just doing some data analysis with this ad-hoc query, there is no doubt that using the ordinal position is quickest, simplest way to do it. If it were production code, I would take some time to look into different options like the second option above, which is also extremely simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the distinct qty query in a subquery then order it

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FLOOR(QTY))
        FROM (select distinct QUOTE_PRICE.QTY
        from QUOTE_PRICE
        JOIN QUOTE_LINE
        ON QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE_LINE.QUOTE_ID
        WHERE QUOTE_PRICE.QUOTE_ID = QUOTE.ID) t
        ORDER BY QTY asc
        FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')
```